# Wordpress: remove page search by date

Tags: wordpress, search, post

In wordpress, I want to remove page: http://domain.com/2016/03/16/
I mean: when somebody access this page, content is not found 404

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. First and easier is using a plugin. This one for example: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/
Or you can edit your .htaccess file located on the root of your website. Then add a rule to redirect the page you want to the 404 page of your site.

`#This allows you to redirect /2016/03/16/ to /404/ (assuming the path to your 404 page is /404/
Redirect 301 /2016/03/16/ http://domain.com/404/`